# Why aren't files being updated? (Rails4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, best-in-place

I'm using [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/tree/rails-4) to update the names of photos I've created with [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). The file name is being updated in the database but the file actually stored (/public/system/photos/attachments/...) isn't being updated to reflect the changed name.

The result is the app looking for the new file name that doesn't exist:

**No route matches [GET] "/system/photos/attachments/000/000/011/original/new_file_name.jpg"**

Photo controller:

```
def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update_attributes(photo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to(new_photo_path, :notice => 'Photo was successfully updated.') }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@photo) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@photo) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Photo (new) view:

```
 <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
   <%= best_in_place photo, :attachment_file_name, :type => :input %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`best_in_place` is giving you mechanism to give a new name for your attachments whereas `Paperclip` is used for either uploading a `new attachment` or `replacing with` a new attachment. In your `update` action, you are passing a new `attachment_file_name` which will only update the file name of the attachment in the database but not the physical file name. 
In order to do that you'll have to rename the file using `File.rename` utility.

For example:

```
 def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    original_file_path = @photo.attachment.path
    folder_path = original_file_path.gsub(@photo.attachment_file_name,"")

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update_attributes(photo_params)
        unless @photo.attachment.path == original_file_path
          File.rename(original_file_path, folder_path + @photo.attachment_file_name )
        end
        format.html { redirect_to(new_photo_path, :notice => 'Photo was successfully updated.') }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@photo) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@photo) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: almost.. the I tried out your code but I think it was missing end after File.rename. I tried to edit your answer but I can't because it's less than six characters. Maybe you could try? Then I can mark your question as accepted.

Comment: @Sheldon `end` is not missing for `unless`. I have aligned the code so that you could match the blocks.